# Share constants between C# and Javascript in MVC Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'd like to use string constants on both sides, in C# on server and in Javascript on client.
I encapsulate my constants in C# class

```
namespace MyModel
{
        public static class Constants
        {
            public const string T_URL = "url";
            public const string T_TEXT = "text";
     . . .
        }
}
```

I found a way to use these constants in Javascript using Razor syntax, but it looks weird to me:

```
@using MyModel
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var T_URL = '@Constants.T_URL';  
            var T_TEXT = '@Constants.T_TEXT';
     . . .
            var selValue = $('select#idTagType').val();
            if (selValue == T_TEXT) { ...
```

Is there any more "elegant" way of sharing constants between C# and Javascript?
(Or at least more automatic, so I do not have to make changes in two files)

Comment: This is the best way I've found. Are you wanting something that will scrape your .cs files for `public const string` and automatically recreate those values as `var` in the javascript for you? I can't imagine that would be inherently useful all the time.

Comment: An addendum to my last comment. I failed to notice these were constants. That, on the other hand, is useful.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The way you are using it is dangerous. Imagine some of your constants contained a quote, or even worse some other dangerous characters => that would break your javascripts.

I would recommend you writing a controller action which will serve all constants as javascript:

```
public ActionResult Constants()
{
    var constants = typeof(Constants)
        .GetFields()
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(null));
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(constants);
    return JavaScript("var constants = " + json + ";");
}
```

and then in your layout reference this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("Constants")"></script>
```

Now whenever you need a constant in your scripts simply use it by name:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(constants.T_URL);
</script>
```

Comment: The javascript file get cached on the client side?

Comment: For every JS file I have to do this? And if I want to separate Constants for each JS/View ?

Comment: @Patrick, since the js is cached on the client why care? Simply put your constants in a single script.

Comment: And can I have a resource based constant for Multi-Language front-end like this: public static string centerButtonTitle = HeelpResources.MapCenterButtonTitle; ? centerButtonTitle is the label of a google map that is put by javascript.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought that has it's in the server-side, the dynamic resource language was not able to refresh the value of the constant to present in the client side

Comment: Great solution but be careful that you don't go creating a javascript file that contains constants not intended for general consumption.

Comment: nice trick! does this work with MVC's minification? Since this is not a js file that we can specify within a bundle, and the constants from this may be getting used in js files that are specified within a bundle, will there be a variable name mismatch?

Answer (score 5):

You can use an HTML helper to output the script necessary, and use reflection to grab the fields and their values so it will automatically update.

```
    public static HtmlString GetConstants(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");

        foreach (var prop in typeof(Constants).GetFields())
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("    var {0} = '{1}'", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(null).ToString()));
        }

        sb.AppendLine("</script>");
        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather then storing your constant data in a C# class, store it in a static config/constants file.

```
// Constants.json
{
    "T_URL": "url",
    "T_TEXT": "text"
}

// Constants.cs

// load the json from a file stream into a constants object

// Constants.js

window.Constants = $.getJSON(url);
```

Simply store it as some file format (json, xml, cvs, whatever) then load it up from both the client & server.

This means your either creating a class in the C# on the fly at runtime using black magic reflection or just have a hashtable / dictionary containing your constants under keys.

[`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), [`JsonReaderWriterFactor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory.aspx)

Comment: close but not close enough. He needs something to use reflection (more or less) on the server to generate things for the client.

Comment: @jcolebrand where the constants are is arbitary if there in a class or in a file. I prefer to keep them in a file.

Comment: but you would still have to duplicate effort to keep .cs, .json, .js in sync.

Comment: @jcolebrand the `.cs` & `.js` are static write once files. The `.json` is dynamic

Comment: Could you elaborate on the black magic please? That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Shagglez what ever your doing it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Raynos I am trying to set up a unified format for constants that could be used across several languages to store error codes. Ideally I'd like to have them strongly typed for C#, would would mean parsing the file (JSON probably) and creating a DLL that could be used in my application. Is that a bad idea? What's an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

My version to create a namespaced javascript object from my C# constants that is immutable:

```
public static HtmlString GetConstants<T>()
        {
            StringBuilder jsConstant = new StringBuilder();
                jsConstant.Append("myApp." + typeof(T).Name + " = Object.freeze({");
            foreach(var item in typeof(T).GetFields())
            {
                jsConstant.Append(string.Format("{0}:'{1}'",item.Name,item.GetValue(null).ToString()) + ",");
            }
            jsConstant.Remove(jsConstant.Length - 1, 1);
            jsConstant.Append("})");
            return new HtmlString(jsConstant.ToString());
        }
```

Used like this in Razor:

```
@(HtmlHelpers.GetConstants<MyApp.Infrastructure.ApplicationConstants.SomeConstants>())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add the constant as a `data-` value to the button/link calling the JavaScript code.

Your view:

```html
<button data-url="@T_URL" ...>
```

Your script:

```
$('button').click(function(event) {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    ...
```