# Reusable text in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, text, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just learning MVC4, so this is a very basic question.

I have a string of text that I'd like to display on multiple pages. What is the best practice to accomplish this (other than copying/pasting it into each cshtml)?

Comment: If it's not view specific, and it's universal you could add it to the _layout

Comment: You could also consider storing your strings as resources and retrieving where necessary through the a `ResourceManager`, this has the added benefit of being able to do localization down the road if you ever need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's going to be on every page, put it in the _layout file as Maess suggested.  If you only want it in specific views, you can create a partial view and just insert that wherever you want it to display.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up going through the partial view route. It seems to work fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You could define them in code within a static class:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyConstants
    {
        public static string message = "Whatever I wanted to say";
    }
}
```

and use them in cshtml:

```
@using MyNamespace
<h1>@ViewBag.Title @constants.message    </h1>
```

Also have a look at the answers to VikViks question: [Share constants between C# and Javascript in MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217028/share-constants-between-c-sharp-and-javascript-in-mvc-razor)

Comment: Cool... I'll have to try this out when I get a chance to breathe. I had read a number of articles saying "ViewBag is evil", so was worried about being lambasted if I used it.