# Resource Languages values in external javascript file

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

What is the best approach to have Resource Multi-Language values in an external JS file?

I found different approaches but I can't put them in external JS file, and I would like to get feedback:

1º var in the View

```
<script> var buttonLabel = @Resources.MapCenterButtonTitle</script>
```

2º Hidden Input in the View

```
@Html.Hidden("buttonLabel", Resources.MapCenterButtonTitle)
```

3º I tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/6217109/1480877 but it does not allow Resource values in const var

4º Any other that could be better then those.

Thanks

Comment: You can make the JavaScript an ashx and do the replacements in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

script file:

```
function InitSomething(resources){

}
```

view:

```
@{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var resources = serializer.Serialize(new { buttonLabel = Resources.MapCenterButtonTitle });
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("src")" onload="InitSomething(@resources)"></script>
```